# ios UIImagePickerController not working

Tags: ios, ios8

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init] ;
[imagePicker setAllowsEditing:YES] ;
[imagePicker setDelegate:self] ;
[imagePicker setMediaTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage, nil]] ;
[imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary] ;
[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil] ;
```

Comment: Post you question with proper format.

Comment: Can you add the output console ? What is the error ?

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Add Delegate

```
@interface APPViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>
```

Step 2: Initialize UIImagePicker on click button Action

```
- (IBAction)selectPhoto:(UIButton *)sender {

    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];    
}
```

Step 3:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    self.imageView.image = chosenImage;
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];   
}
```

Step 4:  Dismiss controller

```
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker  
{    
      [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];     
}
```

Note: Post your Question with detail description

Answer (score 0):

You are using UIImagePickerController as a variable not as an attribute or property, it means that it will be released at the end of your function. Set your UIImagePickerController as an attribute or property and then the delegate will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a UIPopoverPresentationController, make sure you dismiss the popover before presenting the imagePicker.  Otherwise, it will not be shown.